# authenticated users are sent to correct route but need to refresh to see the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

so i am building a simple transaction application to build my skills and i am new to authentication i am using localstorage to create "tokenn" item whenver a user signs in/ signs up
I want to check if the user has tokenn then they should not access the signin signup pages (ie redirected to the Dashboard page) and vice verca for not having the tokenn

i did hell lot of things to tackle tried conditional rendering, tried to add a authCheck component to components which should be shown to signed users etc etc
but everytime i came to two things

1. not working
2. working but need to refresh (in both cases ie when unauthenticated users try to navigate to Dashboard and other components as well as authenticated users try to navigate to signin and other components)

here is the App.jsx code where i tried
[app.jsx](https://github.com/mujtbkhn/paytm-mujtaba-frontend/blob/main/src/App.jsx)

i also tried checking if the token exists then show this else this and various other things but nothing is working

If someone can help me with this it would be really really appreciated
also heres the git repo for this : [frontend](https://github.com/mujtbkhn/paytm-mujtaba-frontend)
[live](https://paytm-mujtaba.netlify.app/)